# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a problem : I want to display data from mysql database via php on the emulator and I find the exception

```
Connection to 127.0.0.1 refused
```

I changed `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` or `10.0.2.1` or `10.0.2.2` it is the same. 
I use *EasyPhp*, I have reset my computer and my server many times but it is the same.
When I execute the link on a browser it works fine.

### AllProductsActivity

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

### JSONParser

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 10);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "getting JSon String from server :-- " + sb.toString());
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

### Stacktrace?

```
03-26 00:21:10.348: W/System.err(334): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:1080 refused
03-26 00:21:10.358: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
03-26 00:21:10.358: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-26 00:21:10.358: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-26 00:21:10.358: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
03-26 00:21:10.379: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-26 00:21:10.379: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-26 00:21:10.389: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-26 00:21:10.389: W/System.err(334):  at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
03-26 00:21:10.389: W/System.err(334):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:128)
03-26 00:21:10.389: W/System.err(334):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
03-26 00:21:10.389: W/System.err(334):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-26 00:21:10.429: W/System.err(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-26 00:21:10.451: W/System.err(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-26 00:21:10.458: W/System.err(334):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-26 00:21:10.471: W/System.err(334):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-26 00:21:10.471: W/System.err(334):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-26 00:21:10.478: W/System.err(334): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:1080 - Connection refused
03-26 00:21:10.488: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
03-26 00:21:10.488: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
03-26 00:21:10.488: W/System.err(334):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
03-26 00:21:10.488: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-26 00:21:10.498: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
03-26 00:21:10.498: W/System.err(334):  ... 15 more
03-26 00:21:10.528: E/Buffer Error(334): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 00:21:10.548: E/JSON Parser(334): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-26 00:21:10.578: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:131)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-26 00:21:10.659: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 4 more
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334): Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e50508 that was originally added here
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e50508 that was originally added here
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:118)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:58)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-26 00:21:12.128: E/WindowManager(334):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 00:21:16.099: I/Process(334): Sending signal. PID: 334 SIG: 9
```

Comment: why you removed the stacktrace?

Comment: @Jenz why you removed the stacktrace?

Comment: 2 things, 1) check your firewall connection as it may be blocking incoming connections and 2) check your server `ini` file to allow incoming connections from all

Comment: i thried everything but it can't solve my problem. what i don't understant is that it was working before with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and when i use netbeans for my J2ME-PHP-MYSQL application i can connect with `localhost`. why not with Eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the 127.0.0.1 in the device it points to the localhost in the device. You have to use the IP of your Server instead.

Best regards

Comment: Depending on what emulator you are using, you can alter its forwarding table to redirect messages for the localhost to your remote host. This will make the code test fine when not deployed on an emulator.

Comment: the IP of my server is 127.0.0.1

Comment: The IP of the Computer where your Server runs is 127.0.0.1?

Comment: If you are looking from the device the server runs what IP it has then, of course, it will be on localhost. What you need to look for is the network IP of the device the server runs on. Or does your server run on the emulator as well?

Comment: the same project worked fine before and don't no why ut does no more works. 
I works with _EasyPhp_ my server is _Apache_ and when i go in Apache configuration i can see `ServerName 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: i have changed the port in apache but it can't solve my problem. what i don't understant is that it was working before with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and when i use netbeans for my J2ME-PHP-MYSQL application i can connect with `localhost`. why not with Eclipse?

Comment: Have you also changed the URL in your Android APP. The URL have to point to the IP adress oft your Server. AS example 192.168.20.10/products.php

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is another machine.

Find the IP of your computer and use that instead 127.0.0.1

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the IP of the local host for each individual machine - it can not be used as the IP to access a server from different machine. Look for another IP (in console - ipconfig for windows; ip or ifconfig for unices).

Comment: i used the ip adress of my computer but it can't solve my problem. what i don't understant is that it was working before with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and when i use netbeans for my J2ME-PHP-MYSQL application i can connect with `localhost`. why not with Eclipse?